Are wildcard ssl certs insecure for multi-level domains?
I have an SSL cert that has a CN set for *.mydomain.com. This seems to be fine for my 1st level subdomains, e.g. forum.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. However, on 2nd level subdomains (e.g. www.forum.mydomain.com), Chrome complains that the cert is not valid. Why is this so, and how do I fix it?

Because the wildcard matches exactly one level in DNS (one 'label') and not more. See RFC 2818 if HTTPS (as 'www' usually is) or RFC 6125 otherwise. Incidentally this is why StackExchange meta domains used to be meta.$topic.stackexchange.com but moved to $topic.meta.stackexchange.com when they enabled SSL/TLS back around 2018. All webserver certs since about 2015 should have SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) extension which supersedes CommonName attribute, and SAN can contain multiple servernames, depending on CA at least tens and often hundreds or more; use that.

Or simply stop putting www in front of every subdomain as it is unnecessary.

This question is similar to: SSL Wildcard Certification that covers more than one layer of subdomains?, SSL Wildcard Certification that covers more than one layer of subdomains?, IIS: Multi level subdomain with wildcard not resolving
